# Curve fitting in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting

For example i have 5 point like this,

```
(1,1) (2,-1) (3,2) (4,-2) (5,2)
```

Now,

- 1) I want a function to interpolation these points in Matlab.
- 2) I want to Plot this function.
- 3) Read a number from input and write F(x) to output.

How can I do this??

Comment: What kind of interpolation would you like to use? Are you simply trying to draw a "smooth" graph or would you like to fit some special function?

Comment: a polynomial function solve my problem

Comment: I don't see the reason for down votes. The question can be improved, but without any comments by those down voting, it will not help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fit a polynom to given datapoints you can use `polyfit(x,y,n)` where `x` is a vector with points for `x`, `y` is a vector with points for y and `n` is the degree of the polynom. See example at [Mathworks polyfit documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html)

In your case:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5];
y=[1,-1,-2,-2,2];
n=3;
p = polyfit(x,y,n)
```

And then to plot, taken from example

```
f = polyval(p,x);
plot(x,y,'o',x,f,'-')
```

Or, to make a prettier plot of the polynomial (instead of above plot)

```
xx=0:0.1:5;
yy = erf(xx);
f = polyval(p,xx);
plot(x,y,'o',xx,f,'-')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure what a good fit would be and want to try out different fit, use the curve fitting toolbox, `cftool`. You will need to create two vectors with `x` and `y` coordinates and then you can play around with `cftool`.

Another option would be to use `interp1` function for interpolation. See [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want polynomial interpolation, take a look at the `polyfit` function. It is used generally for least-squares polynomial approximation, but if you choose the degree+1 to be the same as the number of points you are fitting it will still work for you. For interpolation as you probably know, the degree of the interpolant is equal to the number of points you have -1. So for your example points above you need a degree 4 polynomial. Here is a link to the mathworks documentation

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

If you split your points into 2 vectors of respective x and y coordinates, you can simply obtain your interpolating polynomial coefficients in a vector `b` where

```
  b = polyfit(x,y,4)
```

and based on your data above, your x and y vectors are

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [1 -1 2 -2 2]
```

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo your question asks for interpolation, not plotting. Use the answer above to obtain the coefficients, then use `polyval` to evaluate them at the points you want to plot, and use the `plot` function. Mathworks has lots of documentation on this function. This should be plenty of information to get you started - im not going to do all the work for you

Comment: why are you angry? today, i start to learn matlab. and still learn nothing. excuse me

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo I am not angry - I am sorry if you think this